# Unexpected behavior of IEnumerable<T> in C#

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I found some unexpected behavior in .NET 6. Could somebody please explain it to me?

Consider the following code:

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double? Value { get; set; }
}

public static IEnumerable<A> GetAList()
{
    var arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    return arr.Select(_ => new A { Name = _.ToString() });
}

var aList = GetAList();

foreach (var a in aList)
{
    a.Value = 1.0;
}

var aResult = aList.ToList();
```

The fields `Value` in `aResult` are equals to `null` How can that be possible?

Comment: Can you show us the expected vs actual output? Edit your question to include these details.

Comment: As a side note I find the choice of `_` as parameter name to be awful, unless you are trying to obfuscate your code in which case it is excellent. The `_` is generally used as a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards). In your case it's not discardable, because you use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The lambda in `arr.Select(_ => new A { Name = _.ToString() })` method is a projection that is, *unless you buffer it yourself*, evaluated **every time you iterate it**. Therefore, the data you get when you `foreach` over the data to assign values is **completely separate to** (different `new A {...}` instances) the data you get when you later `.ToList()` it. Perhaps use

```
var aList = GetAList().ToList();
```

so that it *actually is a list*, i.e. buffered. Now, when you iterate it, it'll be the same data instances each time.

You can see this in action by having the lambda tell us what it is doing:

```cs
        return arr.Select(x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            return new A { Name = x.ToString() };
        });
```

You'll see the numbers are written *twice*, not once, for the two separate and independent iterations.